# Timed out receiving message from renderer: 59,996 using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, render

I have a problem with my script.
after about 10 times I run the commands below this error comes out:

```
Timed out receiving message from renderer: 59,996
```

I use as ubuntu operating system

- selenium version is 3.141.0
- chrome version = 88.0.4324.150
- chromewebdriver = 88.0.4324.96 for linux 64

How can i solve?

I can't understand what this error might be about

[image: error]

```
import time
import os
import datetime

from selenium import webdriver #importa libreria selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys #importa funzione per centrare elemento su pagina 
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains #importa funzione per centrare elemento su pagina 
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select #importa funzione per selezionare elemento da menu' a discesa
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from logger import logger as l
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

email='email'
password='password'
url='https://www.unieuro.it/online/Console-Playstation-5/PlayStation-5-pidSONPS5DISC' #url del oggetto da tenere monitorato
numerocel='cellular'

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("enable-automation")
#chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--dns-prefetch-disable")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-xss-auditor")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(60)  # Timeout 15 seconds
#driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')  # devifinisci il nome del driver

driver.implicitly_wait(60) 
driver.maximize_window() #massimizza il browser
driver.get(url) #andare al indirizzo richiesto sul campo url
time.sleep(5) #pausa prima di eseguire il comando successivo

#verifica disponibilità
dis=None
while not dis:
    try:
        i=None
        i = datetime.datetime.now()
        print ("Data e ora corrente = %s" % i)
        dis=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.btn-orange-normal:nth-child(2)') #verifica se è presente il bottone aggiungi al carello
        print('in stock unieuro')
    except Exception as e:
        print('out of stock unieuro')
        time.sleep(10)
        driver.refresh()  #ricarica la pagina e riesegui il controllo
        time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: I tried as recommended to remove all your options but it didn't solve the problem? in my opinion it is a refresh problem is there another way to do it? or could it be the while not function that's not okay?

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Timed out receiving message from renderer: 59,996
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) was unable to communicate with the *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

The most probhable reason is you have configured the *ChromeDriver* too many unnecessary *arguments*.

---

### Solution

Remove the unnecessary arguments and retest as follows:

```
import time
import os
import datetime

from selenium import webdriver #importa libreria selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys #importa funzione per centrare elemento su pagina 
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains #importa funzione per centrare elemento su pagina 
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select #importa funzione per selezionare elemento da menu' a discesa
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from logger import logger as l
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

email='email'
password='password'
url='https://www.unieuro.it/online/Console-Playstation-5/PlayStation-5-pidSONPS5DISC' #url del oggetto da tenere monitorato
numerocel='cellular'

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(60)  # Timeout 15 seconds
driver = webdriver.Chrome('path/to/chromedriver')  # devifinisci il nome del driver
driver.get(url) #andare al indirizzo richiesto sul campo url
```

Comment: I tried as recommended to remove all your options but it didn't solve the problem? in my opinion it is a refresh problem is there another way to do it? or could it be the while not function that's not okay?